# Why my endpoint is returning the Laravel homepage instead of the response?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to do an API with laravel and this is my `UserController` which is inside App\Http\Controllers

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $users = User::all();
        return $users;
    }

    public function create(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'fullname' => 'required|string',
            'gender' => 'required|in:male,female,other',
            'birth_date' => 'required|date',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    
        $user = new User([
            'fullname' => $request->fullname,
            'gender' => $request->gender,
            'birth_date' => $request->birth_date,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password
        ]);
    
        $user->save();
    
        return response()->json(['message' => 'User created successfully'], 201);
    }
}
```

This is my api.php:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/register', [UserController::class, 'create']);
```

In postman I am sending the following request to `http://localhost:8000/api/register`

```
{
    "fullname": "test",
    "gender": "Male",
    "birth_date": "10-02-1998",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

As headers i have `Content-Type` `application/json`
Instead of getting an error or the response with the message that a user has been created, i get the Laravel home page (The one when you first run a laravel project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try use the headers

```
 "Content-Type": "application/json"
 "Accept": "application/json"
```

Comment: What is the explanation to this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in this [article](https://dev.to/arxeiss/force-json-response-on-all-api-routes-in-laravel-29h) they try to explain it better, but I understand that if there is no Accept header, Laravel gives priority to HTML over JSON.

Comment: it's better to give explaination so the poster know how it works too